# Java API for Semantic Similarity / Relatedness between two "WORDS"

Tags: java, semantics, similarity, wordnet, ws4j

i need to find out semantic similarity / relatedness between two input words. Following words are similar or related in real world:-

```
- genuineness, genuine, genuinely, valid, reality, fact, really   
- painter, painting, paint
```

Following is my code snipped that i took from [here](http://w3facility.org/question/ws4j-returns-infinity-for-similarity-measures-that-should-return-1/)

```
    ILexicalDatabase db = new NictWordNet();
    RelatednessCalculator lin = new Lin(db);
    RelatednessCalculator wup = new WuPalmer(db);
    RelatednessCalculator path = new Path(db);

        String w1 = "truth";
        String w2 = "genuine";
        System.out.println(lin.calcRelatednessOfWords(w1, w2));
        System.out.println(wup.calcRelatednessOfWords(w1, w2));
        System.out.println(path.calcRelatednessOfWords(w1, w2));
```

i am using WS4J Api (ws4j1.0.1.jar) with java 1.7 in eclipse 3.4. i am getting following results that makes no sense or may be my perception is wrong.

[image]

If my approach is wrong, please let me know if i want to work out similarity between words, then what other api i should have been using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the words are not found in the dataset you have configured, and so it simply returns a score of `0.0`: For example, the following nonsense words result in a score of `0.0` as well:

```
ILexicalDatabase db = new NictWordNet();
RelatednessCalculator lin = new Lin(db);
RelatednessCalculator wup = new WuPalmer(db);
RelatednessCalculator path = new Path(db);

String w1 = "iamatotallycompletelyfakewordwithagermanwordinsidevergnügen";
String w2 = "iamevenmorefakeandstrangerossiskajafoderatsija";
System.out.println(lin.calcRelatednessOfWords(w1, w2));
System.out.println(wup.calcRelatednessOfWords(w1, w2));
System.out.println(path.calcRelatednessOfWords(w1, w2));
```

Unfortunately, I can't tell what your configuration is like, and the link you supplied does not seem to work (any more, at least). However, the JAR for ws4j 1.0.1 at [Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ws4j/downloads) includes its own information content file (named *ic-semcor.dat*) which is configured in the file *similarity.conf*:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# The following option is supported by :
#               res, lin, jcn

infocontent = ic-semcor.dat

            # Specifies the name of an information content file under 
            # data/. The value of this option must be the name of a 
            # file, or a relative or absolute path name. The default 
            # value of this option ic-semcor.dat.
```

Using this setup, I get the same results for the words you listed in your table. Therefore, you should look more into the configuration of the individual `RelatednessCalculator` implementations for the different metrics.

Comment: @jaykio77: Can you please accept this answer if it helped you?-- I'm currently dredging for some extra reputation points. Thanks a lot.